# Create an Alias for my DNS

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos, dedicated-server

I own a dedicated Server in OVH, and my DNS are :

> Primary DNS : ks221074.kimsufi.com
>   Secondary DNS : ns.kimsufi.com

My OS is Centos 5, and I don't have a strong experience with Linux, I installed WHM/cPanel in the server.

I want to create an alias DNS eg : ns1.domain.com, ns2.domain.com

so my clients can point they domain names to ns1.domain.com, ns2.domain.com, instead of ks221074.kimsufi.com, ns.kimsufi.com.

I have 2 additional IP adresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add CNAME's for those entries pointing from ns.domain.com to ks221074.kimsufi.com.  I suggest to [RTFM](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/SimpleDnsEditor). For CNAME you can use the simple DNS editor:

To add a CNAME record:

- Select a domain from the drop-down menu.
- Type in the Name and CNAME of the CNAME record.
- Click Add CNAME Record.

Comment: I registred two nameservers in the registrat both ns1 and ns2 are pointing to the primary and secondary IP addresses, and from WHM I edited the domain.com DNS zone, and I added 2 CNAME records pointing ns1/ns2 to the primary/secondary nameservers.